# Tableau API Query View Data returns <Response [200]> instead of csv data

Tags: rest, tableau-api

As per the tableau documentation (link: https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/api/rest_api/en-us/REST/rest_api_ref.htm#query_view_data)  when i run the code i should get the data in csv result but when i run the code, i get nothing.

I have converted the curl command provided in the documentation to python script.

```py
import requests

headers = {
    'X-Tableau-Auth': 'e31I7MKBQaOwIHQL1EpB4A|xjzzRWqqEvXkbzUv3jWNf92nEquSAae2',
}

response = requests.get('http://10ay.online.tableau.com/api/3.3/sites/17ba3780-6888-4966-b513-3f5cfd13bb7a/views/2c31387b-d5a6-42d5-8cd6-adee2c2aa1d5/data', headers=headers)
```

I expect the result to be a csv data, but the actual output is nothing.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like request.get will only return response code. [Here is some documentation.](https://realpython.com/python-requests/#the-get-request)

Because you are getting a 200 response code, its likely that there is some underlying data which can be explored using the other functions listed in the documentation, such as:

```
 requests.content
```

However, I might suggest trying Tableau's [Python Server Client](https://github.com/tableau/server-client-python/blob/master/samples/export.py) for the task at hand.